# iphone MediaPlayerController does not show the media player

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,

I am developing an app which contains 3 tab view control. One each for audio, video and images.

When i select the video tab, I have all the items displayed in the table view format so that on selection of any cell, the video is shown. 
Example.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] ;

[moviePlayer play];

}
```

The problem with this is though I am able to play the video I am unable to see the video and can hear only the audio.
In addition, if I were to close the app while the video is playing, and start it the app, the application crashes.

Can you please let me know how should I go ahead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some more time, I have found out that for version above 3.2 one has to use MPMoviePlayerViewController.

The use of the same resolved the issue.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion ] doubleValue] >= 3.2) {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];

    if (mediaPlayer) {
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer];
        mediaPlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile ;
        [mediaPlayer.moviePlayer play];
        [mediaPlayer release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this technote from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1240.html

To summarize, you need to add the movie player controller's view as a subview of your app's view.